# Persisting app settings/preferences in database as JSON?

Tags: c#, sql, json, asp.net-mvc, application-settings

This is one of those needs that keeps coming up over and over in the web applications that I tend to build. We're talking about needing to persist a structure like this:

```
public interface IAppSettings
{
    string AppName { get; set; }
    string SupportEmailAddress { get; set; }
    bool IsEmailEnabled { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

I often start by simply using the built-in AppSettings in web.config, but then they usually tend to move into being persisted in the database (for various reasons). In that case, I usually do one of two things:

## 1. Store the settings as key-value pairs in a two-column "Preferences" table

...where both the key and value columns are simple `nvarchar` strings. This is similar to using AppSettings in web.config, but stored in the database instead.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Preferences] 
(
    [Key] [nvarchar(50)] NOT NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL
)
```

Or...

## 2. Store the settings as a single row in a multi-column "Preferences" table

...where each column represents a named preference with a specific data type. The benefit is that I can more accurately capture data types (strings vs booleans, etc.), but the downside is that adding properties requires for schema changes, rather than just adding more key-value rows like in approach #1.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Preferences] 
(
    [AppName] [nvarchar(50)] NOT NULL,
    [SupportEmailAddress] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [IsEmailEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

I haven't exactly loved either of those two approaches, so I was thinking about another approach this time around:

## 3. Store preferences as a serialized JSON string in a single column, single row "Preferences" table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Preferences] 
(
    [PreferenceValues] [nvarchar(max)] NOT NULL
)
```

The potential benefits that come to mind are:

- The structure would be easy to deserialize into an `IAppSettings` object and use inside the app.
- JSON would allow for a more complex/nested structure (complex sub-types, arrays, etc.). For example, an array of "Admin Email Addresses" or something like that.
- Adding/removing properties would be a simple matter of updating the whole object and overwriting it as a new serialized JSON string in the DB.

Potential downsides:

- Using a single row, single column table seems like misusing a relational DB. However, if one needs to persist the data in SQL, and that data isn't needed for joins and other "relational" things, then I'm not sure I see harm in that. Is it really any worse than approach #1 above?
- Data could get in a weird state if the `IAppSettings` definition changes, and the persisted JSON data is out of date and can now no longer get deserialized properly. But there are ways to manage JSON document versions in the world of NoSQL, so I'd just have to adopt some approach for that, I assume.

**Any thoughts on this? Anybody been down this path before and has any wisdom to share?**

Comment: Your question is _primarily opinion-based_.  Why not do what works for you?

Comment: many sql databases these days natively support json ( including querying )

Comment: What is your db engine? switch to postgres and store as `jsonb`

Comment: I personally prefer 1st option (easy read, easy write, easy update) and 3rd option (json friendly, most db engine supports json query nowadays, updating & inserting is a little bit tricky though). I don't like 2nd option since every time you need to add / remove app settings, you'll need to do migration. Purely my opinion!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @MickyD, I am looking for tried strategies from experience (from the community). Opinion-based, perhaps, but there is rarely one way to do anything, so I don't see a problem in asking the question here. As far as which DB engine I'm using, it's SQL 2014 for this project (client constraint, I can't switch to something else). I know SQL 2016 has some more native JSON support, but unfortunately I don't have that in 2014. The overall strategy of using JSON though would still be the same, though.